# SQL Server Read and Write Latency

Tags: sql-server

I am facing some slowness in my production SQL Server 2012 database.

When I check the latency, it shows the Read latency of my .MDF file exceeds the critical (21 ms) sometimes and most of the time in warning level (now 18 ms).

What is the cause of this? How can I resolve this? Is this is the cause for DB Hang?

Comment: Is your server under very heavy load? Does it have extremely slow disks? Are some of the disks showing errors (check https://www.howtogeek.com/134735/how-to-see-if-your-hard-drive-is-dying/ or an equivalent tool)?

Comment: Exceeds it by how much? How do you define slowness? 21ms isn't super, but it shouldn't cause your database to "hang" (whatever your definition of hang is). Have you determined which queries are slow? I would be surprised if an IO latency of around 20ms is causing extreme issues so you probably have a couple of slow queries. Investigate those (use sp_whoisactive) and post back with the queries and query plan.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple possibly causes.

- Fundamentally, the IO subsystem is overloaded. SImple like that. YOu have a budget of IO operations provided by the hardware. You ned more, so requests queue up. Be aware of third party influence - some people use a SAN and may be on shared discs and another user may use up the IOPS budget at times (backup, anti virus check on a large file server) leaving you with not enough for normal load.
- This can be based on way too little memory, which SQL Server uses for caching. THere is no way to make a table scan efficient on a 100gb table when you have 2gb memory. Plenty of people run their database servers with literally less memory than their laptop has.
- This CAN be based on very bad queries that avoid the use of indices resulting in a lot of table scans. Example is a text field and a search "LIKE '%blabla%' - leading % means no index, sorry. Another one is using a function on the field, which invalidates indices on the field for the query (example: DateAddd(1, [expiration] < GETDATE()) - the DateAdd should be on the other side, so an index on [expiration] can be used).
- This CAN be based on missing/wrong indices, resulting in a lot of table scans. Sounds like the last point, but here the index is missing.

That sort of sums it up. As usual I would start on 2 sides: Hardware (SSD is the only fast and cost efficient way) and analyzing slow queries. The later can lead to astonishing results because a great many developers these days are ignorant to the use of indices or the actual power of a database server and have no clue how to formulate proper queries, resulting in the database server doing a LOT more work than it has to do.

You basically need to start by looking at the queries running and evaluate those.